# Синхронизация ПК и Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. 
Я студентка и только начинаю изучать Java. Преподаватель предложил для курсовой написать на Java  программу на ПК и аналог на Android и синхронизировать их, в связи с чем у меня возникли вопросы:

1. Реально ли это сделать?
2. Как?

Comment: а сохранять данные нужно где то в облаке (то есть, попросту говоря - где то на отдельном сервере в сети), тогда проблема синхронизации сильно упрощается.

Comment: Согласен, посмотрите Parse.com, можно пользоваться бесплатно. Там можно базу общую создать. Есть библиотеки и туториалы для каждого поддерживаемого языка программирования.

Comment: @argamidon, представьте, пожалуйста, что машины, на которых находятся работающие программы, находятся за сетевыми экранами (а это далеко не редкость), каким образом вы сможете к ним подключиться?

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, реально.
   Для синхронизации данных, которые будут на пк и на телефоне, их нужно где-то хранить (т.е. создать базу данных или использовать уже готовую), первый коммент тому подтверждение.
2. Нужно будет создать БД и создать схожий графический интерфейс для приложения (если, конечно, задание продразумевает его наличие).
   Далее из приложения на ПК и на телефоне нужно будет отправлять запросы к серверу (где будет база данных), и получать/отправлять данные.
   Т.е. связка будет примерно такая: ПК <---> сервер <---> android.

Суть в том, что для пк и андроида нужна единая база данных.

Answer (score 0):

А по-моему, облако необязательно. ИМХО достаточно добавить функцию в программы  - что-то вроде "подключиться к остальным и синхронизироваться". Т.е. принудительно распростанить информацию на работающие программы на других компах/виртуальных машинах. А если запустить программу, где нет синхронизированных данных, то указать ей адрес компа с последними данными. Но этот вариант является костылем и велосипедом на случай, если лень заниматься облаками.